# How to load a javascript i18n properties file in spring?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, internationalization

I need javascript i18n in my web application which is based on Spring MVC.

For javascript 18n I am using jQuery.i18n.properties and the URL where I found it is http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/

When I run a sample application, it works properly but when I integrate it in my application it does not work.

Basically my javascript code is not able to load the js properties files. When I show a alert using keys, it always shows key but not the key values.

Here is my project structure.

```
 └── WebRoot
   ├── resources
   │   └── scripts
   │       ├── i18n
       ├   ├── resourceBundles
       ├   ├    ├── Messages_en
       ├   ├    ├── Messages_fr
       ├   ├── jquery.i18n
       ├   ├── jquery.i18n.properties
       ├──jquery-1.4.min
       ├──jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min
   └── WEB-INF
       ├── spring
       │   ├── app
       │   │   ├── controllers.xml
       │   │   └── servlet-context.xml
       ├── jsp
       │   ├── home.jsp
       │   
       └── web.xml
```

I have a resources folder where I have a scripts folder where I have my jquery js files. scripts folder also has a i18n folder where I have my i18n js files. i18n folder also has resource bundles folder where I have en and fr messages files.

In web inf I have a jsp folder which has my home jsp file. It has following code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    loadBundles('en');
});

function loadBundles(lang) {
jQuery.i18n.properties({
    name:'resources/scripts/i18n/resourceBundles/Messages', 
    mode:'both',
    language:lang
});

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `mime-type` to the *web.xml* file (Tested in Tomcat 6)

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>properties</extension>
    <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding the `path` :-

```
name:'Messages', 
path:'resources/scripts/i18n/resourceBundles/', 
mode:'both',
language:'en'
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I tried it but even it is not working. When I saw the logs, it is giving this error "ResourceHttpRequestHandler: handleRequest - No media type found for ServletContext resource [/resources/scripts/i18n/resourceBundles/Messages_en.properties] - returning 404 - (ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java, line 117)". Any ideas?

Comment: @Ashish - Are you trying to read it with `mvc:resources` or using jQuery to load it for java scripts?

Comment: Hi. I am using jQuery to load it for java scripts.

Comment: seems path has to be '/scripts/i18n/resourceBundles/'. please check