# How to load i18n properties files?

Tags: jquery, spring

I need JavaScript i18n in my web application which is based on Spring MVC.

When I run a sample application it works properly but not when I integrate it in my application.

My JavaScript code is not able to load the properties files.

Here is my project structure.

[image: Here is my project structure.]

jquery in login.jsp:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        loadBundles('de');

        // configure language combo box
        jQuery('#lang').change(function() {
            var selection = jQuery('#lang option:selected').val();
            loadBundles(selection !== 'browser' ? selection : null);
            jQuery('#langBrowser').empty();
            if(selection === 'browser') {
                jQuery('#langBrowser').text('('+jQuery.i18n.browserLang()+')');
            }
        });

    });
        function loadBundles(lang) {
                            jQuery.i18n.properties({
                                name:'messages', 
                                path:'src/main/resources', 
                                mode:'both',
                                language:lang, 
                                callback: function() { 
                $("#msg_welcome").text($.i18n.prop('user.success')); $("#msg_selLang").text($.i18n.prop('user.lang', lang)); 
                }
        });
    };
```

login.jsp:

```
                          <body>
    <div id="mainWrapper">
        <div class="login-container">
            <div class="login-card">
                <div class="login-form">
                    <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
                                            <form:form action="${loginUrl}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="users">
                        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <p>Invalid username and password.</p>
                            </div>
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                <p>You have been logged out successfully.</p>
                            </div>
                        </c:if>
                        <div class="input-group input-sm">
                            <label class="input-group-addon" for="username"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Enter Username" required>

                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group input-sm">
                            <label class="input-group-addon" for="password"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></label> 
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                        </div>

                                                    <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                                        Language:
                                                    <select id="lang">
                                                    <option value="browser">Indicated by the browser</option>
                                                            <option value="en">en</option>
                                                            <option value="de" selected>de</option>
                                                            <option value="ru">ru</option>
                                                      </select>
                                                      <span id="langBrowser"></span>

                                                      </div>

                                                    <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                                        <label><input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" name="remember-me"> Remember Me</label>  
                                                    </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />

                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <input type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default" value="Login">
                        </div>
                    </form:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Chrome developer console:
[image: Chrome developer console]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a javascript i18n properties file in spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247752/how-to-load-a-javascript-i18n-properties-file-in-spring)

Comment: try to remove `.properties` from the filename

Comment: It is not a duplicate. Remove .properties doen't work.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Error 404 (Not Found):

http://localhost:8084/src/main/resources/messages_en.properties?_=1467642928278 404 (Not Found)

In chrome developer tools

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate, check out all the answers and comments from the post that I mentioned

Comment: try to access it via the browser without "src/"

Comment: :) 
I checked all the related answers to that question

Comment: it is obvious that the solution is simple, but I do not see it

Comment: try to access the resource via browser, has the server the rights to access it? If its not found, than some settings are maybe wrong.. maybe the url is wrong

Comment: There is no `src/main/resources` when your app is deployed, nor can you access your classpath from the web browser.

Comment: and which the correct way?